# Tabbar not showing after a segue?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uitabbar

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my `UITabBar` is not showing after a segue. Basically, the hierarchy goes like:

Tabbar > Navigation Controller > View Controller > Navigation Controller > View Controller

I tried removing the second `UINavigationController` in order to make that transition, the first (blue) `UIViewController` has a slide up menu (just a basic `UIView` with buttons, that's Y offset is off the screen, with basic animation) and when a button is clicked, it leads to the appropriate `UIViewController`. Once the View controller is presented, you no longer see the `UITabBar`. Basically, the View Controller tops it. I tried changing the segue from modally presented to push, but it doesn't change it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a screenshot of the `UIStoryboard` to illustrate that better. PS: The `UITabBar` is not visible on this `UIStoryboard`, but it's shown in the simulator. I can guarantee that.

UPDATE: Full screen of the storyboard added

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is your navigation code?

Comment: @Lu_ what do you mean by "Navigation code"?

Comment: Please take a complete screen shot of `UIStoryboard` and also confirm `Hide Bottom Bar On Push` is unchecked . Let me see your new screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Set your hierarchy like:-- Navigation > Tabbar > Navigation Controller > View Controller
When u try to push view controller from tab u set tabbar as navigation and most important thing is set your root view hierarchy.

set your break point where view controller is present and then in debug area "po(navigation cotroller)" it's may be nil.

I,it will help you.

Comment: I tried this, I've embedded the `UITabBar` into a `UINavigationBar` but it still doesn't work. It still presents the View Controller on top of the tabbar,

Comment: @Dani can u print navigation controller.is it nil?

Comment: It's not nil. It gives me `<UINavigationController: 0x10281ba00>`. So it does exist

Comment: @Dani can you please upload full screen photo of storyboard.

Comment: I've added it to the initial question above. Please, take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Heirarchy of viewController:- Navigation1 > ViewController1 > Navigation2 > ViewController2.(By the this is not good way to handle this type of hierarchy)

when I push from  ViewController1 to ViewController2 it will be present because of now set Navigation2 means ViewController2  set as root view Controller.

But I want to push ViewController1 to ViewController2 I need to change root view controller as ViewController2.

Now when I need to remove Navigation2 at that time change root as ViewController1.so,as per your question you need to change root view controller.